# What is the probability that at least one group is not represented?

Tags: probability

A group of 20 persons from Region A is constituted from 7 persons from group X, 10 persons from group Y and 3 persons from group Z. 5 persons are randomly selected to form a group B. What is the probability that there is at least one group not represented by group B?

So far what i have is this:

$$
\frac{\binom{17}{5}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{20}{5}}= \frac{7727}{15504}= 0.49839
$$

is this the right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your term $\binom{17}{5}$ counts all choices that leave out Z. The term $\binom{10}{5}$ counts all choices that leave out Y. Their 
sum double-counts the choices that leave out Z and Y, that is, consist of members of X alone. So we must subtract $\binom{7}{5}$ to get rid of the double-counting.

Your sum also double-counts the choices where only Y is represented. So we must also subtract $\binom{10}{5}$ from the sum. There are no choices where only Z is represented, so no further adjustment is necessary.

**Remark:** The strategy was basic Inclusion/Exclusion, deliberate overcounting followed by adjustment.

Comment: hmm i guess i should try to figure it out using unions and intersections, because i still dont really understand it.

Comment: Well, take events $P$, $Q$, and $R$, where $P$ means  chosen from $X\cup Y$ and $Q$ means chosen from $X$ and $Z$. Your first two terms count these. Each includes in its count "chosen from $X$ alone" which is not allowed. So from each we must subtract $\binom{7}{5}$, the choices from $X$ alone. It is related to $|P\cup Q|=|P|+|Q|-|P\cap Q|$.  But we don't want $P\cup Q$, we want $(P\cup Q)\setminus(P\cap Q)$. And there is another term like that to worry about. The reason there are not three terms is that $Z$ is too small.

Comment: oh i see where i got confused by your answer, i made an error in the question. It is the probability that AT LEAST one group is not represented in group B.

Comment: When I have the time I will answer the modified question.

Comment: So we have:

$$\frac{\binom{17}{5}+\binom{13}{5}+\binom{10}{5}-\binom{10}{5}-\binom{7}{5}}{\binom{20}{5}}\approx 0.48078$$
correct?

Comment: The expression is correct. I have not checked the calculator work that led from that to your $0.48078$.